# How Can I Round All Time Using SAS?

Tags: time, sas, rounding

I have a little problem and appreciate if anyone could help me.

What I'm trying to do is basically round the time part to the nearest 30 minute.

My question is how can I do rounding data using SAS.

This is my command:

```
DATA sampledata;
INFORMAT TRD_EVENT_TM time10.;
FORMAT TRD_EVENT_TM TRD_TMR time14.;
INPUT TRD_EVENT_TM;
TRD_TMR = round(TRD_EVENT_TM, 1800);
INFILE;
00:14:12
00:16:12
09:01:23
09:46:32
15:59:45
;
PROC PRINT; RUN;
```

But I want to round all time, Not five of them.I am using big data.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Can you explain your question better?  You seem to have already posted the answer to how to round time to the nearest 30 minutes. What is it that you do NOT know how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data Sampledata_RT;
    set Sampledata04;
    TRD_EVENT_ROUNDED = intnx('minute30',TRD_EVENT_TM,1,'b');
    TRD_EVENT_ROUFOR = put(TRD_EVENT_ROUNDED,hhmm.);
    CountedVOLUME = TRD_PR*TRD_TUROVR;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are asking how to do this rounding on other data, not just your datalines in the example above I suggest you separate these two tasks into two different data steps.

First you create your sample data (this you can exchange for your main data later)

```
DATA sampledata;
    infile datalines;
    INPUT TRD_EVENT_TM hhmmss8.;
datalines;
00:14:12
00:16:12
09:01:23
09:46:32
15:59:45
;
RUN;
```

Then you perform the rounding of the time variables.

```
data test;
    set sampledata;
    format TRD_EVENT_TM TRD_TMR time.;
    TRD_TMR = round(TRD_EVENT_TM, 1800);
run;
```

Hope this is the answer to the question you had.

Answer (score 0):

The above code only rounds up, but if you want it to round based on the actual number of seconds then you can use this instead.

```
data sampledata;
format TRD_EVENT_TM rnd time8. ;
set initialdata;
/*this rounds time up if there are more than 30 seconds*/
if scan(vvalue(TRD_EVENT_TM),3,":")>=30 then 
rnd= intnx('minute',TRD_EVENT_TM,1,'b');
/*drops the seconds if its less than 80*/
else rnd=intnx('minute',TRD_EVENT_TM,0,'b');
run;
```